# How do I create reports that pull from a range of data?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I've been tasked with creating an access database and its complexity has grown as time has gone along.  I'm now at the end of this task where I have to create a set of reports that are created from this application and I can't sort it out.

This is my schema:

[image: Drug Trials Database]

The reason why I have a TrialRates table, and a seperate TrialRateCosts table with the same foreign keys and only one different type of data, is that every Trial has a "pre-configured" rate for whatever rate is being used in that trial.  This might be (probably is) the wrong design and I'm entirely open to suggestions on how to improve it.

My problem is that the report I am generating seem quite simple, mainly, to get Trials between a certain date range, and count where certain boxes are ticked or  not.  But I can't figure out how to do this.  I've searched and checked youtube and most of the videos are very beginner level and don't talk about how to pull data in from a variety of data sources.

My questions are these:

1) Is there a better way to do this schema?

2) How do I generate a report that would show the sum of RateCosts for a certain trial?  Bearing in mind that the costs for a trial is stored in the TrialRatesCost table...

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding 1): To evaluate the quality of the schema you need to provie sample data. Regarding 2) What have you tried? It seems like a SQL query with (SUM...) would provide what you need.

Comment: Each trial can only have a single record in either intermediate table. It seems that both intermediate tables should be moved to the trials table. You haven't given enough information about how a "pre-configured" rate is defined. Is it based on the rate type? or perhaps a "trial type"?

Comment: @ChristopherD. Sorry about that, it's based on a Rate Type.  So, "Simple Dispensing" has an ID of 3 (for example).  The Trial that has uses this type of Rate might have an ID of 1.  TrialRateCosts stores the TrialID, and the RateID, and the cost for that trial (which is configured beforehand).  TrialRates has the TrialID and RateID, and the date of when it occured.  These get their "labels" from RateTypes... does that make sense?

Comment: So if you move the RateCost to the RateTypes table, add "DateOccured" and "RateID" to the Trials table, delete the TrialRates and TrialsRatesCost tables and join Trials and RateTypes on the RateID field, would you have enough flexibility in the model? If not, due to varying RateCosts per Trial, I would also add a RateCost field to the Trials table. When a new Trial is created, add [RateType].[RateCost] value to the [Trials].[RateCost] field to show the pre-configured rate. If the cost deviates from the pre-configured rate, overwrite the pre-config rate with the actual RateCost in trials table.

Comment: @ChristopherD. but when you have multiple Rates and DateOccured's per trial, how do I express that in the Trials table?  A trial has multiple "actions", and those actions have rates.

Comment: Ah I see. Then your relationship between trials and trialrates, and trials and trialratescost should be one to many, not one to one. I'd also consider that DateOccurred and RateCost should be in the same table if both fields are linked to the same event. If that isn't true, then the structure is fine, you would just need to update the relationships.